# Custom NSCursor for ToolbarItem

Tags: macos, cocoa

After reading several questions on the subject here, I have successfully used "custom" cursors for textfields (labels), window contentViews, and buttons using a couple of approaches but I can't make either work for a toolbarItem. Here's the current code:

CustomToolbarItem.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CustomToolbarItem : NSToolbarItem

@end
```

CustomToolbarItem.m:

```
#import "CustomToolbarItem.h"

@implementation CustomToolbarItem



- (void) awakeFromNib {
    // setup trackingarea for cursor control (mouseEntered/mouseExited)
    NSTrackingArea *trackingArea= [[NSTrackingArea alloc]
                                   initWithRect:self.view.bounds
                                   options: (NSTrackingInVisibleRect |
                                             NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited |
                                             NSTrackingActiveAlways)
                                   owner:self
                                   userInfo:nil];
    [self.view addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] push];
}


- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] pop];
}

@end
```

I've also tried setting `owner:` to `self.view`, but no joy.

The alternate approach that works  for textfields, buttons, etc. that support the drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}

- (void)resetCursorRects {
    [self addCursorRect:self.bounds
                 cursor:NSCursor.pointingHandCursor];
}
```

I can't directly modify/address the ToolbarItem's view in XCode's interface builder so I'm stumbling in the dark here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `[self.view addCursorRect:self.view.bounds cursor:NSCursor.pointingHandCursor]`?

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didn't work either. I suspect the issue is that I can't figure out how to override drawRect for the toolbarItem's view inside a subclass of toolbaItem. Since I can't address the view in the interface editor, I can't reassign the view's class.

Comment: Why do you want to override `drawRect`?

Comment: Does the toolbar item have a view?

Comment: Based on autocomplete for `self.view`, I would say yes. But no view is visible in the xib hierarchy.

Comment: `self.view` could be `nil`. Put a control (button, image view) in the toolbar and create a subclass of the control.